# While retrieving values from Preference, it is repeating 20 times

Tags: android

Hi I am storing BigInteger[] array into Preference, This is working fine, but while retrieving i am getting the same value 20 times, can someone tell me what's wrong with the code :

```
final String DELIMITER = "BOND";
final int DELIMITER_LENGTH = 4;
String str = null ;
//BigInteger [] integer = new BigInteger[50];

for(int l = 0; l < arrayTimes.length ; l++){

    if(str == null){

        str = arrayTimes[i].toString() + DELIMITER;
    }else{

        str += arrayTimes[i].toString() + DELIMITER;
    }
}

savePreference("your_key", str);
Log.d("Prefs", "Array Time Saved");

String strone = loadPreference("your_key");
ArrayList<BigInteger> myBigInt = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
while(strone != null){

    int subStringLastIndex = 0;
    if(strone.contains(DELIMITER) && strone.length() != DELIMITER_LENGTH){

        subStringLastIndex = strone.indexOf(DELIMITER.charAt(0));
        myBigInt.add(new BigInteger(strone.substring(0, subStringLastIndex)));
        strone = strone.substring(subStringLastIndex + 4);
    }else{

        strone = null;
    }
}

for(int m = 0; m < myBigInt.size(); m++){

    Log.d("Prefs", myBigInt.get(m).toString()); //Here i am printing values
}
```

Comment: Does your array contain 20 values? if yes I feel you are saving single value to the array 20 times hence you get same value 20 times when you retrieve. Check whether different values are getting saved to array.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a typo.  Your for loop uses l but you reference the array with i.  If arrayTimes has 20 items, you'll add the same value to the string 20 times.